# How to click on check box along with any desired value in another column with selenium?

Tags: c#, list, selenium, checkbox, webdriver

I am using selenium web driver with C# for automating my tests.
Today i am facing a problem in which i have to select an check box along with a desired value in another column.

Here check box is having different id's.

ex: I have a list of .jpg images & suppose i have to select rose.jpg from list, its not mandatory that always rose.jpg is displayed second or third in list , so i need that selenium will read rose.jpg & selects check box adjacent to it., here their is one more issues that every check box is having different id's so i can not use this code:

```
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'rose.jpg')]/preceding::td/input[@name='ctl00$bodyPlaceHolder$deviceTabContainer$pnlRestoreFiles$deviceRestore$gvRestore$ctl02$chkSelRestore']").Click()
```

here ct102 can be ct103 or can be ct104.

Please help what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code on the rest of the page, it's hard to know exactly what the solution might be, but--if you're using the `@name` section of your XPath to distinguish the checkbox you desire from other possible checkboxes, you might instead use the index number of the `input`. Something like:

```
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'rose.jpg')]/preceding::td/input[1]").Click()
```

In this example `[1]` means the first (topmost in the page's html) XPath to meet this criteria (using `[2]` will be the second element to meet this criteria, etc). If the checkbox's siblings are always the same number and appear in the same order (which is often the case), then something like this will work for you. That way, it doesn't matter that the `ct###` is dynamically generated, since you won't be using that to identify your element.

If you *must* use `ct###`, then you could iterate through the possibilities, or use try/catch blocks, but it would be a weak way to go, since it would be hard to account for every possible `ct###`, and tedious to hard code them in, and would make your code slower than using the `[#]`, if that avenue is available to you.